# Questionnaire design puzzle

Tags: c#, object-oriented, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, wcf

I am designing a small questionnaire web service application but however I would like if someone can look at my design and see if it good approach I am taking.

The application has the following classes:

- `Questionnaire`
- `Answer`
- `IQuestionRepository`
- `QuestionRepository implements IQuestionRepository`

In the `QuestionRepository` I have three methods:

- `GetQuestionnaire()` returns a list of questionnaire to the client
- `GetAnswerOptions(int questionId)`

  When creating a questionnaire object this method is called inside the questionnaire constructor to get a list of possible answer for each question. This is the part 
  I am not sure to create an repository object inside the questionnaire constructor because I was thinking what would be the best way to inject the possible answer list into the questionnaire object.
- `GetMarks` mark the questionnaire result

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Questionnaire
    {


        public Questionnaire() {
        }


        public Questionnaire(int _questionId) {
            QuestionId = _questionId;
            PossibleAnswer = new QuestionRepository().GetAnswerOptions(_questionId);
        }

        [DataMember]
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string QuestionAsk { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string UserAnsResponse { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string PossibleAnswer { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int QuestionnaireType { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public bool? isCorrectAnswer { get; set; }

    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Answer {
        [DataMember]
        public int AnswerId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string AnswerText { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Questionnaire Question { get; set; }
    }
    public interface IQuestionRepository
    {
        List<Questionnaire> GetQuestionnaire();

        double GetMarks(List<Questionnaire> qList);

        string GetAnswerOptions(int questionId);
    }
public class QuestionRepository : IQuestionRepository
{

    //this is a hack normally will pull data from a data source like DB/CSV
    public static List<Answer> GetAnswerLibrary() {

        List<Answer> AnsLibrary = new List<Answer>();

        AnsLibrary.Add(new Answer() { AnswerId = 1, AnswerText = "London", Question = new Questionnaire() { QuestionId= 11 } });
        AnsLibrary.Add(new Answer() { AnswerId = 2, AnswerText = "paris", Question = new Questionnaire() { QuestionId = 22 } });
        AnsLibrary.Add(new Answer() { AnswerId = 3, AnswerText = "Warsaw", Question = new Questionnaire() { QuestionId = 33 } });
        AnsLibrary.Add(new Answer() { AnswerId = 4, AnswerText = "Port louis", Question = new Questionnaire() { QuestionId = 44 } });
        AnsLibrary.Add(new Answer() { AnswerId = 5, AnswerText = "Berlin", Question = new Questionnaire() { QuestionId = 55 } });

        return AnsLibrary;
    }
    //this is a hack normally will pull data from a data source like DB/CSV
    public static List<Questionnaire> GetQuestionLibrary() {
        List<Questionnaire> QuestionLibrary = new List<Questionnaire>();

        QuestionLibrary.Add(new Questionnaire(11) { Title = "Geo", QuestionAsk = "What is the capital of England", QuestionnaireType = 1 });
        QuestionLibrary.Add(new Questionnaire(22) { Title = "Geo", QuestionAsk = "What is the capital of France", QuestionnaireType = 1 });
        QuestionLibrary.Add(new Questionnaire(33) { Title = "Geo", QuestionAsk = "What is the capital of Poland", QuestionnaireType = 1 });
        QuestionLibrary.Add(new Questionnaire(44) { Title = "Geo", QuestionAsk = "What is the capital of Mauritius", QuestionnaireType = 1 });
        QuestionLibrary.Add(new Questionnaire(55) { Title = "Geo", QuestionAsk = "What is the capital of Germany", QuestionnaireType = 1 });

        return QuestionLibrary;
    }
    public List<Questionnaire> GetQuestionnaire()
    {
        return GetQuestionLibrary();
    }

    public string GetAnswerOptions(int questionId) {

        string ans = string.Empty;

        var Anslibrary = GetAnswerLibrary();
        Dictionary<int, string> GetPossibleAnswerCombination = new Dictionary<int, string>(); 
        if (Anslibrary.Count > 0){
            try {

                bool CheckIsAnswerExisr = Anslibrary.Any(x => x.Question.QuestionId == questionId);
                if (CheckIsAnswerExisr) {

                    var ValidAnswer = Anslibrary.Where(x => x.Question.QuestionId == questionId).FirstOrDefault();
                    GetPossibleAnswerCombination.Add(ValidAnswer.AnswerId, ValidAnswer.AnswerText);
                }
                else {
                    throw new Exception("Missing Answer for questionid" + questionId);
                }
                Random rnd = new Random();

                while (GetPossibleAnswerCombination.Count < 3) {

                    var randomIndex = rnd.Next(0, Anslibrary.Count - 1);
                    var GetRandomPossibleAnswer = Anslibrary[randomIndex];
                    if (GetRandomPossibleAnswer.Question.QuestionId != questionId && !GetPossibleAnswerCombination.ContainsKey(GetRandomPossibleAnswer.AnswerId)) {
                        GetPossibleAnswerCombination.Add(GetRandomPossibleAnswer.AnswerId, GetRandomPossibleAnswer.AnswerText);
                    }
                }
                var sheffuleAnswer = GetPossibleAnswerCombination.Values.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray();
                ans = string.Join(" ,", sheffuleAnswer);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.ToString();
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }

    public double GetMarks(List<Questionnaire> qList) {

        var AnsLibrary = GetAnswerLibrary();

        double result = 0;
        double TotalNumberofQuestion = qList.Count();
        int UserValidAnswer = 0;

        try {
            if(TotalNumberofQuestion > 0) {

                var filterQuestionaire = qList.Where(q => q.UserAnsResponse != null).ToList();

                foreach(var q2 in filterQuestionaire) {


                    bool checkOnlyAnswerQuestion = AnsLibrary.Any(x => x.Question.QuestionId == q2.QuestionId);

                    if(checkOnlyAnswerQuestion) {

                        string city = (q2.UserAnsResponse).Trim();
                        bool checkifValidAnswer = AnsLibrary.Any(x => x.Question.QuestionId == q2.QuestionId && x.AnswerText == city);


                        if(q2.isCorrectAnswer == true && checkifValidAnswer == true) {
                            UserValidAnswer++;
                        }

                        if(q2.isCorrectAnswer == false && checkifValidAnswer == false) {
                            UserValidAnswer++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                result = UserValidAnswer / TotalNumberofQuestion * 100;
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {

            ex.ToString();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Some quick remarks:

- A questionnaire is a series of questions, yet you seem to mistake it for a question.
- `_questionId`: parameters shouldn't start with an underscore.
- Should a `Question` really have a `QuestionId`? Why not simply `Id`?
- `UserAnsResponse` is an odd name.
- `QuestionAsk` is an odd name.
- `isCorrectAnswer` is a property and thus [should be PascalCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx).
- `qList` is a bad name for a parameter. For one, you've needlessly abbreviated `Questionnaire`. Moreover, what if you make it an `IEnumerable<T>`, will you then rename the parameter since it isn't a `List<T>` anymore? Simply name it `questionnaires`.
- To me, `GetAnswerOptions` suggests it will return a collection, yet it returns a string. The result is stored in the property `PossibleAnswer`, which doesn't suggest a collection. This is all very confusing.
- `AnsLibrary` is needlessly abbreviated; moreover it should be camelCase. (But I guess these won't be there in "real life".)
- `GetQuestionnaire` suggests it returns one Questionnaire, yet it returns a `List<Questionnaire>`.
- `Anslibrary` is needlessly abbreviated; moreover it should be camelCase, and "library" should be capitalized since it is [a compound word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264474.aspx).
- `GetPossibleAnswerCombination` is a name for a method, not for a variable.
- `CheckIsAnswerExisr` is a local variable and thus should be camelCase, plus it contains two typos.
- `GetRandomPossibleAnswer`: not a good name for a variable, plus it should be camelCase.
- `sheffuleAnswer`: contains typos.

---

The whole logic of `GetAnswerOptions` is badly designed.

- Why do `CheckIsAnswerExisr` and then do a `Where`?
- What you wanted to do -- getting the one valid answer to the question -- can be done easily using `.SingleOrDefault()`. Using `.FirstOrDefault()` is seriously wrong, since there shouldn't be more than one correct answer to the question. Moreover, you don't even check if `ValidAnswer` is null, which is a possible result of `.FirstOrDefault()`.
- You get a random answer from `Anslibrary` and only then check if it belongs to the question? And then you check if it perhaps is already in the `GetPossibleAnswerCombination`?
- The whole `try...catch` so you can capture the exception you throw if there are no answers for a question is just overkill.

But really: throw it all away and completely rethink the logic and how you need to implement it.

---

On to `GetMarks`:

- Why is there a `try...catch`?
- Don't needlessly abbreviate: `qList`.
- Why assign `filterQuestionaire` and only use it once?
- Again you first do an `Any()` and then a `Where()`. Just do the `Where()` and go from there.
- Why do you check `q2.isCorrectAnswer`? It's never set anyway!

---

Quite frankly, I'm only scratching the surface. IMHO the basic design of your solution is flawed and all of the above are just symptoms.

Answer (score 1):

You have to much vertical spacing (new lines) which reduces readability.

---

Variable names shouldn't be shortened (`List<Answer> AnsLibrary`). Also there is no convention about the casing style of variables which are local to a method, you should use `camelCase` casing.

In addition, you should stick to the style you choose. Right now you are mixing the casing of local variables.

---

Also there is no convention for where to place an opening brace `{` most C# developers expect them to be on a new line.

If you keep your style you should at least stick to it. Right now you are mixing both styles.

---

The `GetAnswerOptions()` should be improved by using a guard clause like

```
if (Anslibrary.Count == 0) { return string.empty; }
```

this will reduce the horizontal spacing and therefor add readability.

---

A `Random` should be created once and should then be reused.

---

> ```
> catch (Exception ex) {
>     ex.ToString();
> }
> ```

this doesn't add any value to the code. If you want to swallow an exception the `ex.ToString();` should be replaced by a comment stating **why** you want to swallow the exception.

---

The `GetMarks()` method should be improved by adding a guard clause too.

This

> ```
> if(q2.isCorrectAnswer == true && checkifValidAnswer == true) {
>     UserValidAnswer++;
> }
>
> if(q2.isCorrectAnswer == false && checkifValidAnswer == false) {
>     UserValidAnswer++;
> }
> ```

can be simplified to

```
if(q2.isCorrectAnswer == checkifValidAnswer) 
 {
    UserValidAnswer++;
}
```

---